# Unpacked array and package in another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm bringing information from a database and saving it in a variable called `getRows`. When I print `getRows` on `console.log`  this is what shows up:

```
GetRows = [
             RowDataPacket {countId: 3, cHour: 12},
             RowDataPacket {countId: 2, cHour: 14}
          ]
```

When listing this array with `GetRows.forEach((data) => console.log(data));` gives error (is not recognized by the javascript and crashes system)

QUESTION: How do I select these `countId` and`cHour` and store them in `otherArray`?

Comment: can we know the error it gives ?

Comment: The error is probably in the code inside the `forEach`. Please include that code too.

Comment: it should be as this `GetRows.forEach((data) => console.log(data));`

Comment: This format of the array that the database returns to me is not recognized by the javascript, so when I execute `GetRows.forEach ((data) => console.log (data))`, it crashes the system

Comment: I'm using it on nodejs

Comment: https://repl.it/JpMK

Answer (score 0):

Please, forget it. I restarted the system and now it works!.

```
GetRows.forEach((data) => console.log(data));
```

Thanks!